# Can't set the download name of a download file using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I use javascript to let people download gpx file they generated tracking on google maps. This is the code of download function

```
function download(filename, text) {
    var pom = document.createElement('a');
    pom.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
    pom.setAttribute('download', filename);
    console.log(pom['download']);
    pom.click();
}
```

The filename is set correctly, but it isn't showed in google chrome (only "download.txt"). It worked in the past, and it works in firefox but it's not working anymore in google chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to either be a cross-origin change for the way `download` attributes work, or a plain old bug. This has already been [reported as a bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=377317) on the google forums, but like that forum thread shows, relative URLs [do seem to work](http://jsfiddle.net/2PCU2/1/).

For now, this bug (?) is quite new though, and I don't think anybody knows exactly why this is occurring, but it could be that the change is made because of cross-origin concerns.

**EDIT**: This has now been [fixed in Chrome 36](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=373182#c39) ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2PCU2/4/)).